# How to create a raised center tab bar button

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I've examined many GitHub and StackOverflow solutions to creating a raised center tab bar button and tried multiple times into creating one but I always end of right back to square one.

So below are the steps of what I've been doing, if someone can solve the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

1. Created a Tab Bar Controller to navigate to 5 different View Controllers
2. Created a Custom Class for the Tab Bar Controller called CustomTabBarController
3. Inside my CustomTabBarController File is

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupMiddleButton()
   }

func setupMiddleButton() {
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height:64))

    var menuButtomFrame = menuButton.frame
    menuButtomFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtomFrame.height
    menuButtomFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtomFrame.size.width/2
    menuButton.frame = menuButtomFrame

    view.addSubview(menuButton)

    menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "MidPhoto"), for: .normal)
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.addSubview(menuButton)
}

@objc private func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    selectedIndex = 2

}





}
```

That's it. I only edited 1 file (CustomTabBarController) and it works but the image is appearing into unwanted View Controllers and I've done multiple things like: Hide Bottom Bar On Push, `self.tabBarController?.tabbar.isHidden = true`, and so on.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The "canned" image for a `UIButton` is dependent on the actual image size. Based on your code I'd say it should be no larger than 60x60. Have you checked the size of "MidPhoto"?

Comment: The size of my Image is 64x64 and when I run the simulator, it works. It's just the image will still display onto other unwanted View Controllers and when I return back to the root view controller, the image is behind the tab bar.

Comment: I guess my problem with understanding your issue is *"...the image will still display onto unwanted View Controllers..."*. I can't see from your code why - and yeah, I understand, *that's* the issue! Your code clearly has your image - "MidPhoto", right? - as part of a `menuButton` and *nothing* else. So, either this `menuButton` is something more than I can glean or I'm missing something. (1) Am I correct? Is it "MidPhoto" that is "appearing on unwanted View Controllers"? If so, (2) are you using this image elsewhere in your code or in IB? And if not, then (3) could you provide a screenshot?